# Gmaps directions saving routes, waypoints

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map with route (multiple destinations - not just A,B as on the page below). The directions are draggable. I'd like to save the changed routes. The page below is what I was going by...

http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm

Here's what I've got:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
            console.log('reroute');

            var rleg_count = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs.length;

            data.start = {
                'lat':directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat(), 
                'lng':directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng()
            };
            data.end = {
                'lat':directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[rleg_count-1].end_location.lat(), 
                'lng':directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[rleg_count-1].end_location.lng()
            };

            var wp=[];
            var w = [];
            var route = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0];
            for (var l = 0; l < route.legs.length; l++) 
            {
                for(var j = 0; j < route.legs[l].via_waypoints.length; j++)
                {
                    w.push({
                        location:{'lat':route.legs[l].via_waypoints[j].lat(), 'lng':route.legs[l].via_waypoints[j].lng()},
                        stopover:true
                    });
                }
            }

            data.waypoints = w;
        });
```

And the SetRoute function:

```
function setRoute(os)
    {
        var wp = [];
        for(var i=0;i<os.waypoints.length;i++)
        {
            wp[i] = {
                'location': new google.maps.LatLng(os.waypoints[i].location.lat, os.waypoints[i].location.lng),
                'stopover': os.waypoints[i].stopover
            }
        }

        var request = {
            'origin':new google.maps.LatLng(os.start.lat, os.start.lng),
            'destination':new google.maps.LatLng(os.end.lat, os.end.lng),
            'waypoints': wp,
            optimizeWaypoints: false,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        }

        directionsService.route(request, function(res,sts){
            // console.log(res);
            // console.log(sts);
            if(sts=='OK')
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(res);
        }); 
    }
```

The problem is that the code works if there are only 2 destinations (A,B), but as soon as there's more destinations... it doesn't work right... it ignores the other destinations

As far as I've been able to tell the waypoints are correct. There seems to be a problem with multiple destinations and I don't know how to rectify it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the problem with the following update to my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
            console.log('reroute');

            var rleg_count = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs.length;

            data.start = {
                'lat':directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat(), 
                'lng':directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng()
            };
            data.end = {
                'lat':directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[rleg_count-1].end_location.lat(), 
                'lng':directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[rleg_count-1].end_location.lng()
            };

            var wp=[];
            var w = [];
            var route = directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0];
            for (var l = 0; l < route.legs.length; l++) 
            {
                    // Skip first and last leg - for more than 2 legs
            if(l != 0 || l != rleg_count-1)
            {
/* start solution */
                w.push({
                    location:{'lat':route.legs[l].start_location.lat(), 'lng':route.legs[l].start_location.lng()},
                    stopover:true
                });
            }
/* end solution */
                for(var j = 0; j < route.legs[l].via_waypoints.length; j++)
                {
                    w.push({
                        location:{'lat':route.legs[l].via_waypoints[j].lat(), 'lng':route.legs[l].via_waypoints[j].lng()},
                        stopover:false
                    });
                }
            }

            data.waypoints = w;
        });
```